# Using async await with getConnection in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I wanted to know if it is possible to use async await when using transaction with mysql. I created the snippet below using the mysql documentation but the problem below is that if I have multiple queries and I want them to fire one after the another there is no way to specify it without creating a call back hell. Has anyone been able to do it with async await?

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET title=?', title, function (error, results, fields) {
              if (error) {
                return connection.rollback(function() {
                  throw error;
                });
              }

              var log = 'Post ' + results.insertId + ' added';

              connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET data=?', log, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                  return connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw error;
                  });
                }
                connection.commit(function(err) {
                  if (err) {
                    return connection.rollback(function() {
                      throw err;
                    });
                  }
                  //console.log('success!');
                  connection.release();
                });
              });
            });
          });
    })
```

I am using a connection pool by the way as you can see above. If you want to know how the pool is created here is the code:

```
let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 20,
    host: keys.connection.host,
    user: keys.connection.user,
    password: keys.connection.password,
    database: keys.connection.database,
    dateStrings: true 
    // debug:true                //Set this to true for verbose debugging. Leaving this to default for now cause it is creating too many messages at my console
})
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }
    // if (connection) connection.release()
    return
})



pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the returned value of each query/request. You can use promise in every request and store it in an array and do promise all at the end:

```
let requestArray = []
// push each request to requestArray
// then do
Promise.all(requestArray).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

if you do, you need something like async waterfall : async-waterfall : [npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall](https://npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall)
Hope that helps

Comment: I need the returned values

Comment: you would need something like a async-waterfall : https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall